# Is there a way to express the set-theoretic limit in terms of topology, filters or ultrafilters?

Tags: general-topology, limits, elementary-set-theory

The way limits are defined in Set Theory (lim sup = lim inf or limits of indicator functions) looks at odds compared to general definitions in term of topology, filters or ultrafilters. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit . Is there a way to express it similarly to general topological limits? Or the other way around (limits of sequence of real numbers considered as Dedekind cuts actually coincide with Set-theoretic limits)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you put the right topology of $\mathcal P(X)$, the limit of a sequence of subset of $X$ is a topological limit.

The required topology can be described as the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) on $\{0,1\}^{X}$, transferred to $\mathcal P(X)$ in the obvious way.

Unfolding one characterization of product topology, we can also describe this topology on $\mathcal P(X)$ as the topology generated by the sets
$$ \{ A \cup C \mid C\subseteq (X\setminus B) \} $$
for all *finite* $A,B\subseteq X$.

Comment: Why not the order topology?

Comment: By topology generated by the sets, do you mean that these sets are the open sets of this topology (or form a base of them)? I do not get the idea behind these collections of sets, they are basically union of a finite subset of X and an another included in an infinite one which complementary is finite. Looks like as big as P(X).

Comment: @Python: I mean that these sets are a basis for the topology. My description was perhaps not optimally clear, but the the idea here is that to create a neighborhood for some proposed limit $L$, you take any finite subset $B\subseteq X$ and consider $\{ S \subseteq X \mid B\cap L = S\cap L\}$ (and all its supersets) to be a neighborhood of $L$. (This corresponds to taking $A=B\cap L$ in the definition in the answer).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't think that will work. For example, in $\mathbb R$, let $A_n=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb Q \leftrightarrow x<n\}$. The limit of the $A_n$s is $\mathbb Q$, which lies in the open set $\{S\subseteq R\mid \mathbb Z \subsetneq S\}$ But none of the $A_n$s are in this open set. Am I misunderstanding what you mean by "order topology" here?

Comment: Henning, I was spitballing, so there's no reason to expect it to be correct. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Okay. I couldn't quickly find any authoritative definition of "order topology" for a _partial_ order, so I was inclined to believe the set theorist. :)

Comment: I guess you can also consider the Scott topology.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If Wikipedia is right about [what the Scott topology is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity), that won't work either. Because a Scott-open set is upwards closed, the only Scott neighborhood of $\varnothing$ is $\mathcal P(X)$ itself, so every sequence whatsoever would have $\varnothing$ as a limit.

Comment: I think that, at least for this purpose, you can define the order topology as the coarsest topology in which all principal ideals and principal filters are closed.

Comment: Relevant literature: https://doi.org/10.1017/S0017089500003980 notably theorem 4.